# Why do voters usually hate the very politicians they've voted for in the last election?

Tags: election

The most well known example is in the US - people elect a President but the second he enters office his ratings start falling down. Likewise the Senate, the Congress, the state governments and even the mayors are usually disliked, criticized and constantly opposed by large groups of voters.

This sounds like a paradox to me - why can't people elect someone they would like and respect during their time in the office? Why don't all elected politicians have ratings higher than 50%?

Comment: 1) Approval ratings will include those who have voted and those who not, so it is not fair to compare them directly. 2) Even ignoring 1, getting elected with 50% of the votes and getting a 40% support would mean that only one of each five of the politician electors'have changes this mind (assuming that supporters of the other side don't change their minds, too). That is far from "usually", from my POV.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll find a non-opinion-based answer to this but basically, the two-party system. Every election we vote for the lesser of two evils, someone pre-selected by the two parties, who, more often than not, we wouldn't support if not for the other guy who is worse. It's more and more rare that we vote for someone we actually want. We have this impression that elections utilize public opinion to select the most popular person possible. They aren't. They utilize public opinion to rubber-stamp the second least popular option the establishment offers us.

Comment: Voted to close as opinion based in a close run with too broad. But now I'm having second thoughts, maybe too broad would have been better, and really I wanted to rant about bad choices, but there wasn't a option for that.

Comment: People tend to vote for promises. The more you promise, the less you can fulfill. The less you fulfill, the more you discourage your electorate. They find themselves in a situation "it never happened before, but now again!" — someone failed to do what they promised to, let's vote for someone else's promises. No future. :-)

Comment: Also, be, careful, "hate" and "not approve of" are very different. A 40% approval rate of a leader, for example, does not mean "60% of the people hate the leader", despite social media sensationalism to the contrary.

Answer (score 2):

> The most well known example is in the US - people elect a President but the second he enters office his ratings start falling down.

Actually most presidents first have their approval increase from their election percentage.  For example, in 2008, Barack Obama was elected with only 52% of the vote but had a [69% approval rating](http://www.gallup.com/poll/113968/obama-initial-approval-ratings-historical-context.aspx) when he started his term.  Most presidents do have their approval rating slide once they actually start doing things.  For example, Obama's slid steadily until it was below 50%.  Then it started to vary more.

Donald Trump is an odd case in that his approval started exceptionally low and slid a bit after he had taken some actions.  He also did particularly well among those who didn't like either candidate, so he had an unusually large number of "supporters" who didn't really support him.  And he's had few chances to reach out beyond his supporters without abandoning those who did support him.  His "State of the Union" speech (which technically wasn't a State of the Union speech since he hadn't been president long enough) was one opportunity, but his political opponents squelched it quickly with a negative narrative.

> Likewise the Senate, the Congress, the state governments and even the mayors are usually disliked, criticized and constantly opposed by large groups of voters.

The Senate and Congress is because they take approval ratings of the body as a whole but people vote for individual candidates.  If you actually check the approval ratings of individual candidates, they are much higher.

I'd have to see clearer data on what is under discussion in terms of state governments and mayors.